# Layout transitions in Nuxt 3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I have two **layouts** inside `layouts` folder: `default.vue` and `projects.vue`. The content of the layouts is not relevant.

The thing is I'm trying to apply **layout transitions** between two pages `index.vue` and `about.vue` using *the default layout*.

I am following [the documentation](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/transitions#layout-transitions): I have created an `app.vue` file with the following code:

```html
<template>
  <NuxtLayout>
    <NuxtPage />
  </NuxtLayout>
</template>

<style>
.layout-enter-active,
.layout-leave-active {
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.layout-enter-from,
.layout-leave-to {
  filter: grayscale(1);
}
</style>
```

and then I added the property to my `nuxt.config.ts` file, like this:

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  app: {
    layoutTransition: { name: 'layout', mode: 'out-in' }
  },
})
```

But it doesn't work. I have also tried with the property `pageTransition` instead `layoutTransition` and **it works** (don't know why).

It seems that the CSS classes for the layout are not applied if I inspect the code. I have also tried to add the classes inside the `tailwind.css` file with no result.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
I created a main.css in /assets/css and added this to nuxt.config.ts

```
  css: [
    '@/assets/css/main.css',
  ],
```

In main.css I added the CSS transitions as you have above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you managed to find the answer?

If not, I may have a theory, although I'm so sure of it this is correct.

Taking your example is it possible, that **layout transitions** are applied only for transitions between layouts and not pages. For instance from a page with the **default** layout to a page with the **project** layout and vise-versa? This seems counterintuitive from a perspective of having globally applied styles at the upmost root component (in this case like the app.vue as the documentation suggests).

That would also explain why **pageTransitions** work in your case. Does the animation still not work if you change the layout of the **about.vue** to let's say to a layout other then default?

Let me know your thoughts.